# gRPC interceptors golang- nested call

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

I want to call a gRPC function inside another gRPC function (i.e. like a wrapper). Do you suggest gRPC Interceptors for implementing of that? What are the best practices for nested gRPC calls?

Answer (score 1):

If there are two GRPC methods which have intersecting (or shared) logic, I would suggest you to move the common part of their logic into another non-GRPC function, and then just use this new function from both methods. That would be the best option. Interceptors are designed for middleware implementation, but not for such specific use case as yours.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Perhaps I didn't explain it well. Suppose we have two gRPC servers. We call a function in gRPC server A and then from that function we would like to call another function from gRPC sever B and waits to get a response from server A and return the result back to server A. Server A acts like a proxy here. I would like to know what are the best practices for implementing a case like that.

Comment: Well, I think this situation is very common in distributed backends consisting of several layers of services. You just need to build gRPC client B into gRPC server A, and use client to service B inside handler of service. This is very trivial. Perhaps I misunderstood the question?

Comment: I think your understanding is correct can you send me an example of that. I know it is trivial but I would like to see a working example first before applying to my code :)